# How would I do this in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

So, I just started learning Scala today, and have been doing fairly well, but I've run into a wall, with this problem...

I need to do this in Scala, but am having trouble sorting it out:

```
final Filter<GameObject> filter = new Filter<GameObject>() {
    public boolean accept(GameObject o) {
        ...
    }
};
```

ATM I have, but it won't even compile:

```
val filter = new Filter[GameObject] {
    override def accept(o: GameObject) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here is the entire object so far:

```
object Targeter extends LoopTask {

  val filter = new Filter[GameObject] {
    override def accept(o: GameObject) = { true }
  }

  //  Overriding a method in the LoopTask class
  override def loop() = {
    100
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there some standard Scala filter functions, where you pass some lambda function?

collection.filter(lambda x: f(x))

Comment: Compilation error would be also VERY helpful :)

Comment: @fiction Filter and GameObject are written in Java, which I don't have the source to, which means I can't access all the GameObjects in the area, and have to use that filter.

Comment: -1 Not enough detail to help us help you.

Comment: your new code should compile without problems... problem should be somewhere else in the file...

Comment: @Easy Angel I don't see where it could possibly be in the rest of it...  Eclipse is underlining the word Filter (the one after new) and giving me the errors in the other comment.

Comment: @Johnny Have you imported `Filter`?

Comment: Yes, it's right above it.  I also tried doing it like: new com.game.scripting.Filter[GameObject]

Comment: @Johnny I tried to reproduce the problem, but everything compiles without any problems. I had bad experience with eclipse in past. I advice you to try either Intellij IDEA: http://www.jetbrains.org - free and open source community edition or try to use sbt and try to compile it without eclipse: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/

Comment: Alright I'll try that.  Also, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you missed return type:

```
override def accept(o: GameObject) = {...}
```

or

```
override def accept(o: GameObject): Boolean = {...}
```

These two variants are the same (assuming that you actually return some boolean in the body of this method).

---

If you define `accept` method like this:

```
override def accept(o: GameObject) {...}
```

then it's the same as:

```
override def accept(o: GameObject): Unit = {...}
```

And `Unit` is equivalent of `void` in java.

Comment: With those changes I get the following error:  Not found:  value o.  And ')' expected but ']' found.

Comment: @Johnny - Can you add to the question your new code and `Filter` class/interface? it would be helpful

Comment: I don't have the source for Filter, and the only visible method is boolean accept(T t)

Answer (score 5):

Try to keep any code written in Scala as idiomatic as possible, a handy convertor function will help out here:

```
def gameFilter[T](fn: T => Boolean) = new Filter[T] {
  override def accept(x: T) = fn(x)
}
```

Which can then be used as:

```
val filter = gameFilter[GameObject](_ => true)
```

Or if you'll only ever filter on `GameObject`s:

```
def gameFilter(fn: GameObject => Boolean) = new Filter[GameObject] {
  override def accept(x: GameObject) = fn(x)
}

val filter = gameFilter( _ => true )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override def accept(o: GameObject) {
```

should be

```
override def accept(o: GameObject) = {
```

.. this is a standard beginner's mistake.  Also, it would be safer to declare the return type:

```
override def accept(o: GameObject):Boolean = {
```

You know I suppose that you can just use a function to replace your filters:

```
val myFilter : GameObject => Boolean = ...
```

and then you can just do things like this:

```
val gameObjects:List[GameObject] = ...
val filteredGameObjects = gameObjects filter myFilter
```

Comment: Replacing the filter isn't an option, otherwise I would have tried to use the built in filters.

Comment: You could also declare an implicit (GameObject => Boolean) => Filter[GameObject] function.

Answer (score 0):

The "entire object so far" compiles fine assuming the other classes are :

```
  abstract class LoopTask {
    def loop(): Int
  }

  case class GameObject

  abstract class Filter[T] {
      def accept(o:T):Boolean
  }
```